# How do I search for "\n" without a preceding "\r" in vim?

Tags: vim, file-format

Vim won't convert fileformat if it sees inconsistent line endings. How can I find those ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zero-width look-behind assertion

"How do I search for “\n” without a preceding “\r” in vim ?"

```
/\r\@<!\n
```

How do you search and replace these occurances with "\r\n"?

```
:%s/\r\@<!\n/\r\n/gc
```

Get rid of the final "c" if you want to accept every match without confirmation.

Edit: However, if you want an answer that you can remember how to do without having used look ahead/behind assertions a billion times, see Jackson Miller's answer.  Sometimes it is better to simplify your problem and use tools that don't require you to read the manual constantly :)

Comment: The search did the trick for me.
BTW, line endings can be changed with :e ++ff=dos, then :w

Comment: Hey, I like your way better Merlyn. I just tend to get it done with what I know how to do.

Answer (score 3):

How about replacing \r\n with \n and then \n with \r\n.

Should be something like:

```
  :%s/\r\n/\n
  :%s/\n/\r\n
```

Answer (score 2):

To change all line endings that are \r\n  to  \n, use

```
:%s/\r$//
```

This will search for all \r characters followed by newline and replace it with just newline

Answer (score 2):

Use a utility like dos2unix or unix2dos to convert the line endings to the desired format.  There are native implementations of these utilities for both unix and windows systems.