# ^M shows up in git diff, but not vi editor

Tags: android, git, vi

I have copied the piece of code from Windows notepad and pasted to my server file.
It doesn't shows any ^M character in vi editor  but when I do git diff it shows  the ^M character at the places where changes are pasted

I tried to fix it

1. By searching ^M pattern in server file but not able to find that pattern using `:%s/^M//g` in vi editor
2. Also tried `dos2unix` command but it converts entire file hence not useful while using gitdiff as it shows entire file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188737/how-do-i-search-for-n-without-a-preceding-r-in-vim

Comment: Vi is being helpful and hiding dos/unix line endings differences from you. You know where the ^M is, correct, so delete the characters around it in vi and then re-type them.

Answer (score 1):

`^M` is the CR character used (alongside with LF) to encode endlines on Windows.
To show it in Vim type:

```
:e ++ff=unix
```

Then you can proceed with deleting those chars.

You can also search them in Vim with `\r` or remove with `:%s/\r//g`

Comment: ":e ++ff=unix"  introduces ^M character in complete file

Comment: ":e ++ff=unix"  introduces ^M character in complete file
 and removing  all the ^M character from the file gives the differnece in entire file in git diff
Any changes done directly in vi editor also shows ^M character in git diff (not in vi editor).
I just want to remove ^M in  git diff